# How to get the original version of overriden builtin method on builtins module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

At some arbitrary place in code, this exists:

```
builtins.open = my_open
```

I cannot change that code, but it's broken. I need to make sure any `open` calls, including those **from other builtin libraries** use the original open. What I need is something like:

```
orig_open = get_original_method("open")
builtins.open = orig_open
```

In Javascript, I typically solved that issue by creating new window frame and getting the methods from there. How to do it in python?

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard Do you really think your edit improved the question? Is anyone likely to search over `builtin` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the issue here is simply the `open` function, you can always grab [`io.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.open) which is an alias for it:

```
import io
builtins.open = io.open
```

I am not aware of any generic solutions to this even though I would not be surprised if one existed.

Comment: Worked thanks. I'll wait though, to see if someone can come with a generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you want, but you can use the `__builtins__` magic variable to grab the "original" open function:

```
>>> builtins.open = __builtins__.open
```

The "magic variable" is simply an alias for the `builtins` module:

```
>>> __builtins__
<module 'builtins' (built-in)>
>>>
```

You should note however that this is an implementation detail, and other versions of the Python interpreter might not support it. From the Python 3 documentation on the [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) module.

> As an implementation detail, most modules have the name `__builtins__` made available as part of their globals. [...] Since this is an implementation detail, it may not be used by alternate implementations of Python.

Comment: This works in console all right. But if I put it in my python file, it gives me this error: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'open'` I'm new to python, not sure what to think of it.

Comment: @TomášZato Everything worked for me. I'm using Python 3.5.2.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue in standalone file. But as soon as I execute the project that contains problematic code, I get this error. I don't know how to provide any mor useful info in the scope of SO comment.

Comment: @TomášZato Alright, well you might just wanna go with Jim's solution instead.